# what is the difference between xor and or in Haskell

Tags: haskell, xor

So, if `xor` returns `True` if and only if exactly one of its operands is `True` such that:

```
xor :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
xor True True = False
xor True False = True
xor False True = True
xor False False = False
```

My question is:
would `or` be similar but return `True` if one or both of its operands is `True`?

Comment: correct. x in xor is for exclusive

Answer (score 11):

you can write `xor` simply as

```
 xor a b = a /= b
```

also `or` can be simplified

```
 or True _ = True
 or False b = b
```

For fun, you can define all logical functions in terms of nand.

```
 nand :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
 nand True True = False
 nand _ _ = True
```

`not` is easy

```
 not a = nand a a
```

`and` requires two gates

```
 and a b = not (nand a b)
```

`or`, requires three

```
 or a b = nand (not a) (not b)
```

and, `xor` requires four

```
 xor a b = let z = nand a b in nand (nand z a) (nand z b)
```

Comment: thanks you karakfa. but i still curious my logic is right for the logical or. would Logical OR return true as long as one or both operands is true?

Comment: even simpler use dot free style - ```xor = (/=)```

Comment: Try implementing NIMPLY in terms of NAND/NOT. XD

Comment: `nimply a b = not ( nand a (not b) )`