# Second Filtering Condition not working as intended - Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a problem whereby I have a list of tuples `("Song Name", "Artist Name", SalesFig)` and I have to filter out a tuple within that list that contain a specific Song Name and Artist Name and return all the other tuples within that list.

Below is my code:

```
testData = [("No Lie", "Sean Paul feat. Dua Lipa",  100),
        ("Yes Lie", "Sean Paul feat. Dua Lipa",  10),
        ("Fear & Delight", "The Correspondents",  120),
        ("Hello", "Adelle", 4)]

filterTrack :: String -> String -> [(String, String, Int)] -> [(String, String, Int)]
filterTrack songName artistName items = filter p items
    where p (song', artist', _) = songName /= song' && artistName /= artist'
```

Now the problem I am having with the codee is that when I want to filter one of the two songs within the list and enter say `filterTrack "Yes Lie" "Sean Paul feat. Dua Lipa" testData` to remove `"Yes Lie"` from, the list, the program removes the other song by the same artist, `"No Lie"`, as well.

I am unsure why this is happening as I have an expression which requires the entry to not match with songName **`and`** artistName. I could understand why this is happening if there was an `OR` rather than an `AND` as it would be true if either one of the conditions were true.

I would have thought using an `AND` would make is so it returns every tuple that exactly doesn't match with the `Song Name` and the `Artist Name`, not just `Artist Name`

Comment: You probably want to use exclusive or (XOR) there.

Comment: @arrowd. I just did some quick searching on XOR, but isn't the syntax for that the same as `/=` with `xor a b = a /= b` being an example. I found this on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655974/what-is-the-difference-between-xor-and-or-in-haskell)

Comment: I meant using `xor` instead of `&&` in your expression.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand these downvotes.  Code is provided with a test case, and the OP describes the actual and desired behavior.  The question seems entirely on-topic for SO, even if it relates to boolean expressions rather than something specific to Haskell.  If there's some reason for the downvotes, it would be helpful if there was an accompanying comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your filter function:

```
p (song', artist', _) = songName /= song' && artistName /= artist'
```

It is equivalent to this pseudo-code:

```
NOT sameArtist AND NOT sameSong
```

Which is, by De Morgans Theorem, equivalent to:

```
NOT (sameArtist OR sameSong)
```

Which is not what you want, but explains the behaviour you are seeing.

What you want your filter to be is:

NOT (sameArtist AND sameSong)

Which is written as:

```
p (song', artist', _) = not (songName == song' && artistName == artist')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on hints from @arrowd, changing `where p (song', artist', _) = songName /= song' && artistName /= artist'` to `where p (song', artist', _) = songName /= song' || artistName /= artist'` solved my issue.

Comment: Technically, this isn't XOR (exclusive-or).  I think @arrowd misread the question and misled you, even though it led you to the correct solution anyway.  I've updated the answer to avoid confusion to future readers.